# Delayed second review of a reputed journal

Tags: publications

I had submitted an article and I got first decision. I wrote answers and explanations to the reviewer comments and re submitted the article. After 2 months it sent to the same reviewer (as per info given at help section) and i am told that the reviewer has not accepted the invite. It is very surprising, why would the same reviewer who reviewed my article once would not accept the invite to see my answers. Or why would the editor wait for almost 2 months for the reviewer to just accept the invite the review.

Comment: Did you re-write the article itself, or just write separate answers and explanations?

Comment: What was the first decision? If the decision was 'conditional publish' and you tried to fullfill the conditions, than this behaviour is very odd. If the decision was 'publication rejected' for some stated reasons and you addressed the reasons it seems well within their rights to refuse to look at the same paper again.

Answer (score 1):

> After 2 months it sent to the same reviewer (as per info given at help section)....[W]hy would the editor wait for almost 2 months for the reviewer to just accept the invite the review[?]

The timeline seems to vary a lot by field, but sometimes the journal publication process is extraordinarily slow. On the whole, 2 months doesn't seem out of the ordinary to me. If it was just the editor waiting to ask the reviewer, I agree that seems strange, but there may have been some good reason for the delay (e.g. back and forth with this reviewer to see if they would be able to accept it or not).

> and I am told that the reviewer has not accepted the invite.
>   It is very surprising, why would the same reviewer who reviewed my
>   article once would not accept the invite to see my answers.

Unexpected things can happen. For example, the reviewer had some personal tragedy or health emergency. You simply cannot tell, so the best thing you can do is to discuss with the editor of the paper what to do next.

Answer (score 0):

> Why would the same reviewer who reviewed my article once would not accept the invite to see my answers?

Lots of possible reasons:

1. They're too busy.
2. They retired/left academia/changed universities/passed away etc and the editor wasn't aware of the new development.
3. You didn't address their questions properly and they decided they didn't want to waste any more time on your paper.
4. They started up a collaboration with you in the interim, which made them have a conflict of interest and therefore are recusing themselves from the paper.
5. ... (you can probably think of a bajillion possible reasons).

> Why would the editor wait for almost 2 months for the reviewer to just accept the invite the review?

As implicit in your question, one would expect the same reviewer who reviewed your article once will accept the invite to review the revision. The editor undoubtedly thought the same, so they chose to wait almost two months in your case, even though for a new reviewer reviewing a fresh submission they might wait a shorter time.